# Cannot install macvim due to Xcode as "pre-release"

Tags: c, xcode, macos, vim

I'm trying to upgrade my Vim to MacVim by running:

```
$ brew install macvim --with--override-system-vim
```

I'm getting this error message saying that the package cannot be compiled:

```
configure: creating cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/macvim-20161028-10122-1pp1odr/macvim-snapshot-113/src':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I have Xcode 8.1 installed on my machine.  But brew seems to think it's a pre-release version:

```
Warning: You are using a pre-release version of Xcode.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

Comment: Why don't you simply [download](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases) it?

Comment: I have.  But I want to replace my existing Vim (in terminal) and not have to rely on a GUI program in my OS X ..  To do so, I'm trying to run "brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim".  That process seems to rely on a git download of the code / compile.. 

I think the bigger issue here is that I can't seem to compile c/c++ libraries due to some issue with compatibility between OS X 10.12 and Xcode 8.1

Also, I would note that I'm running mac file system in case sensitive mode.. right now that seems to be a potential problem..

Comment: MacVim comes with a CLI executable and a CLI wrapper. Put that wrapper in your `$PATH` and do `$ mvim -v` to start Vim. It's really a two minutes affair.

Comment: I get the same warning when I run `brew install cocoapods`. It seems to install it fine though.

Comment: romainl, that's not the point.. the problem is that the macvim source isn't compiling.. this is a bigger problem than just macvim as you can see by Jeroen's comment.. 

There is a problem with Xcode 8.1 being viewed as a preview version that is not compatible with xcodebuild.


"xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
make[1]: *** [macvim] Error 1
make: *** [first] Error 2
"

Comment: This solved it for me: `cd "$(brew --repo)" && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master && brew update --force`. Source http://discourse.brew.sh/t/you-are-using-a-pre-release-version-of-xcode-but-im-using-8-1-from-mac-app-store/459

Comment: above solution does not work for it.  but i tried this and it works https://gist.github.com/takkii/2f6052749a13e6da3201e2c3fe0f72a4#gistcomment-2936583. just following the command with `Xcode-select --install
xcode-select -p
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select -r` and make again